# Activate/recognize Thunderbolt devices on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: thunderbolt

I am having issues with Ubuntu 22.04 recognizing the thunderbolt devices I plug on the computer, which is on an MSI Z590 motherboard.
The `boltctl list` command comes out as empty, no output.
The `lspci -v` command hangs forever, not completing at all.

EDIT:

We've plugged Akitio Duo eGPU encasings with 2x4GB Nvidia GPUs into it. These are fine with other similar computers with Ubuntu 21.04, but it's the first time we try on this MSI Z590 with Ubuntu 22.04.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sometimes this will depend on what it is that you're connecting. For example, I have some Thunderbolt storage devices designed for Apple computers that refuse to work with anything but macOS. Could you [edit] your question to include some more specifics about what hardware you are trying to connect?

Answer (score 0):

The drivers of the BIOS had an update with "Improved Thunderbolt support" as well as changing the parameters of being able to wake on thunderbolt (switch off).

After those changes were applied, all the devices appeared online (8xGPUs on 3xAkitio Duo + 2 internal GPUs).